# detect text field of an windows application in java

Tags: java, windows, textfield, touchscreen

A computer with touch monitor running in windows OS.
I need to write a java code to detect when user touch in a textfield and then show the windows onscreen keyboard and hide the onscreen keyboard when it is not a textfield.

I have done the work to show onscreen keyboard using :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");
```

but how can i detect textfield (of another application which is NOT written in java) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but if you use java.awt.Robot... allow the user to draw a box around the textfield in the other application to get its coordinates then remember it in your program. Or you could just hardcode the coordinates if they are always in the same place.

Once you know the coordinates you can listen to the mouse input, so when the mousePressed event is triggered, if the coords are within the text box, fire off your method for onscreen keyboard to appear.

This may not work because the user has to have the privilege and allow your app to read the native mouse input.